# Creating a backup partition on Android

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, twrp, bootloader, partitions

It would be lovely if I could manually  allocate a portion of space to create a partition for backup that's separated from the other partions that gets wiped or replaced when flashing a custom rom so for example as root if I can create `/dev/sda99`
Mount it backup the custom rom and other files and in twrp recovery I can mount it again and flash the custom rom and the backup and it doesn't get wiped when I format the data in twrp.
But I don't know if it's even possible.
This is a list of my partition

```
.../files/home # ls -alth /dev/block/by-name/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 3.3K Jul 16 16:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 1.8K Apr 12  1971 .
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 frp -> /dev/block/sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 12  1971 sdc -> /dev/block/sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 bluetooth -> /dev/block/sde5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 featenabler -> /dev/block/sde24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 uefivarstore -> /dev/block/sde41
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 devinfo -> /dev/block/sde28
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 dsp -> /dev/block/sde9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 modem -> /dev/block/sde4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 cmnlib64 -> /dev/block/sde13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 limits -> /dev/block/sde35
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 modemdump -> /dev/block/sde39
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 msadp -> /dev/block/sde32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 splash -> /dev/block/sde34
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 tz -> /dev/block/sde2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 abl -> /dev/block/sde8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 keymaster -> /dev/block/sde10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 vbmeta_vendor -> /dev/block/sde17
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 vm-linux -> /dev/block/sde23
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 xbl_config -> /dev/block/sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 ALIGN_TO_128K_1 -> /dev/block/sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 ocdt -> /dev/block/sdd6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 12  1971 sdb -> /dev/block/sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 12  1971 sde -> /dev/block/sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 xbl -> /dev/block/sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 mdm1m9kefs3 -> /dev/block/sdf8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 mdmddr -> /dev/block/sdd4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 cache -> /dev/block/sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 fsc -> /dev/block/sdf7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 logdump -> /dev/block/sde38
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 mdm1oemnvbktmp -> /dev/block/sdf12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 oplusreserve2 -> /dev/block/sdf14
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 rawdump -> /dev/block/sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 vm-data -> /dev/block/sde44
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 hyp -> /dev/block/sde3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 mdm1m9kefsc -> /dev/block/sdf11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 oplus_sec -> /dev/block/sde27
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 oplusreserve1 -> /dev/block/sdf13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 uefisecapp -> /dev/block/sde20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 ddr -> /dev/block/sdd3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 mdm1m9kefs1 -> /dev/block/sdf9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 oplusreserve4 -> /dev/block/sdf16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 persist -> /dev/block/sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 vm-system -> /dev/block/sda8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 keystore -> /dev/block/sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 mdtp -> /dev/block/sde7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 spunvm -> /dev/block/sde33
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 userdata -> /dev/block/sda11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 multiimgoem -> /dev/block/sde21
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 vm-keystore -> /dev/block/sde43
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 apdp -> /dev/block/sde30
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 engineering_cdt -> /dev/block/sdd5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 oplusdycnvbk -> /dev/block/sdf2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 ALIGN_TO_128K_2 -> /dev/block/sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 oplusreserve3 -> /dev/block/sdf15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 12  1971 sda -> /dev/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 ssd -> /dev/block/sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 aop -> /dev/block/sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 devcfg -> /dev/block/sde14
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 limits-cdsp -> /dev/block/sde36
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 mdtpsecapp -> /dev/block/sde6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 misc -> /dev/block/sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 qupfw -> /dev/block/sde15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 secdata -> /dev/block/sde42
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 apdp_full -> /dev/block/sde31
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 cdt -> /dev/block/sdd2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 cmnlib -> /dev/block/sde12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 dip -> /dev/block/sde29
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 imagefv -> /dev/block/sde25
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 logfs -> /dev/block/sde37
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 12  1971 sdd -> /dev/block/sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 storsec -> /dev/block/sde40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 DRIVER -> /dev/block/sdf18
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 fsg -> /dev/block/sdf6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 mdm1m9kefs2 -> /dev/block/sdf10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 modemst1 -> /dev/block/sdf4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 modemst2 -> /dev/block/sdf5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 multiimgqti -> /dev/block/sde22
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 oplusreserve5 -> /dev/block/sdf17
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 oplusstanvbk -> /dev/block/sdf3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 12  1971 sdf -> /dev/block/sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 boot -> /dev/block/sde11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 dtbo -> /dev/block/sde19
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 12  1971 metadata -> /dev/block/sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 recovery -> /dev/block/sde26
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 super -> /dev/block/sda10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 vbmeta -> /dev/block/sde18
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 12  1971 vbmeta_system -> /dev/block/sde16
.../files/home #
```

I know must of Android uses `mmcblk` as reference for all the partions but the layout on my device is different I don't know why.

As you can see the bootloader `abl` and the recovery are on separated block `sde`

`userdata` and `super` partion are on `sda` block so if were to use `parted` on `/dev/block/sda` to create a partition, is it safe ? Is it going to have an impact on recovery and bootloader? is it even possible to allocate memory without shrinking other partions?
Overall it seems like a risky process but it's worth it